# Is there a quick way to compute the coordinate vectors of $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ with respect to the basis $\mathfrak{B}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a quick way to compute the coordinate vectors of $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ with respect to the basis $\mathfrak{B} = (f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),f_4(x))$ of $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ where $f_1(x) = -\frac{1}{6}(x-1)(x-2)(x-3), \hspace{0.3mm} f_2(x) = \frac{1}{2} x (x-2)(x-3), \hspace{0.3mm} f_3(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)(x-3),$ and $f_4(x) = \frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)$?

I know that we need to find the linear combinations of $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ that equal $1,x,x^2$ and $x^3,$ and then after take the scalars of these linear combinations and put them into vectors, but I'm not sure how to do the computation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is.  Let's assume that we already know that $\mathfrak B$ is actually a basis for degree-$3$ polynomials (we can prove it quickly with techniques similar to the ones below).  Let $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ be the scalars for which the polynomial identity

$$ c_1 f_1(x) + c_2 f_2(x) + c_3 f_3(x) + c_4 f_4(x) = x^2$$
holds.  If the polynomials on the left and right are equal, then they take the same value at each $x$.  In particular, if you plug in $x=1$ then

$$ c_1 f_1(1) + c_2 f_2(1) + c_3 f_3(1) + c_4 f_4(1) = 1^2 = 1.$$

Now, note that $f_1(1) = f_3(1) = f_4(1) = 0$, so this simplifies to $c_2 f_2(1) = 1$, which allows one to immediately isolate $c_2$.

I leave it to you to generalize this to extract $c_1, c_3, c_4$ and again the same for the other basis functions.